# Can I mimic application exit code with wm_copydata?

Tags: c++, c++builder

My first time to post here.

I have build a small application with borland c++, which gets executed through a shell command by a commercial third party application. This second app then waits untill it receive the exit code from my app. What I wanted to do is to send '0' or '1' to the second app by sending the message wm_copydata in order to mimic the exit code. I'm doing it this way because I want my app to send exit code without exitting! Is this possible?

The problem is that the data never arrive nor get processed by the second receiving app. I'm actually not sure if the second app implements code to process wm_copydata messages, I just assume it does...

Will appreciate your help as I'm trying to build an application that interconnect different software from different vendors at our department. Here is the code I'm using:

```
void SendMyMessage(char* command)
{
HWND Hamilton_Window_Handle;
int len;
char title[254];
AnsiString stemp;
AnsiString hname = "HAMILTON RUN CONTROL";
Hamilton_Window_Handle = FindWindow(0,0);
while (Hamilton_Window_Handle != 0)
    {
    len = GetWindowText(Hamilton_Window_Handle, title, 255);
    stemp = UpperCase(title);
    if (AnsiPos(hname, stemp) > 0)
            {break;}
    Hamilton_Window_Handle = GetWindow(Hamilton_Window_Handle, GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }

COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = 0;
cds.cbData = strlen(command) +1;
cds.lpData = command;
SendMessage(Hamilton_Window_Handle, WM_COPYDATA, 0, (LPARAM)&cds);
if(AnsiString(command) == "1")
    {
    Form1->Label1->Caption="Barcodes passed consistency check!";
    Form1->Label1->Font->Color = clGreen;
    }
else
    {

    Form1->Label1->Caption="Barcodes failed consistency check!";
    Form1->Label1->Font->Color = clRed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: no, it's not possible. `WM_COPYDATA` is intended to pass data from one application to another but **both applications** must **know** and **use** this message. Moreover they must share an *interface* for its data. It's not automatic and you can't assume it does because process exit code and this message are unrelated (if the application wait the process to exit why it should accept `WM_COPYDATA`? In case it accept that message then with what structure and for which purpose?). Image if someone else assumes that your application accepts WM_COPYDATA instead of, for example, command line parameters. Do you handle the message with that meaning?

What you may need is the `fork()` command available on Unix. Windows doesn't provide this feature, you can *try* to mimic its behavior using `NtCreateProcess()` but it could be really tricky (and I don't know how it integrates with a complex GUI).

A possible solution is to create some shared memory, copy there all private data and run another process. The second process may then read its state from shared memory while the first one simply terminates with the appropriate exit code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Adriano said, your spawned process cannot return an exit code to the launching process without first exiting itself.  That is why it is called an **exit** code, after all.  Windows does not see a process's exit code until the process terminates.

Comment: Thanks Adriano and Remy for the answers.
 
For our implementation we needed to send data back to the second (commercial app) so that my app remains open waiting for user feedback and at the same time the second app resumes execution after receiving the data. Waiting for the external app to exit is for our working setup is a limitation. I solved the problem as you have suggested by saving the data to a file and having the commercial app reading the content of the file for further processing  while my app remains open.


cheers,

Comment: Exchanging data using files is much slower and more exposed to outside parties than other inter-process communication mechanisms. `WM_COPYDATA` would have worked just fine, or you could have used any number of other mechanisms, such as pipes, sockets, mailslots, ActiveX/COM, RPC, just to name a few.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the alternatives as I was not aware of them except for pipes. You are right, saving and reading to an external file is slow but it is working for the moment...